# Amoebic Sea and a civilization

Tags: culture, civilization, planets

Let's say you had a planet like Darwin IV with a sea like the amoebic sea. How would that affect a civilization that evolved on the planet? All I have so far is they might worship it as a god, they would ride the striding creatures and they wouldn't know about deep se vents and probably wouldn't think ice moons could have life either.

Comment: Apart from not having a clue what Darwin IV and the amoebic sea are (so please add details for those like me), questions along the line of "What are the effects of X on a civilization?" are always too broad. Please narrow it down to a specific problem

Comment: It’s a reference to Alien Planet (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJIgcihiw2Y&t=2851s) basically, a bunch of microorganisms banded together to preserve the little remaining seawater effectively becoming this massive jelly like colony that could reach up and snatch low flying creatures or possible behave like the ocean in Moana to the locals.

Comment: Very opinion based, this is entirely up to you and your imagination.